# Why does fully qualified C# import fail?

Tags: c#, .net

In my main method, I had a line of code -

```
WebRequest reqObj = WebRequest.Create(CompleteDPath + FileName);
```

I added an import - `System.Net.WebRequest`. This causes an error:

> The type or namespace name 'YourProject' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

The error goes away when I change the import to  `System.Net` Why does this happen ?

Actually, I am using this code inside a C# script task of SSIS, an ETL tool. I mention that in case you cannot replicate the problem in plain visual studio and want to declare SSIS as 
a source of the problem.

Comment: Because you import namespaces... not types.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Ba dum tss `:)`

Comment: @SonerGönül - The type or namespace name 'YourProject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? So, this is not really like java :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

> The using directive has two uses:
>
> - To allow the use of types in a **namespace** so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type in that namespace:
>
> `using System.Text;`
>
> - To create an alias for a namespace or a type. This is called a using alias directive.
>
> `using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;`

You can't import a type, you have to import the entire namespace, and that's why  `using System.New.WebRequest` does no work, and your code does not compile.

You could create an alias to `WebRequest`, to prevent entire namespace to be imported, but I personally don't like that solution:

```
using WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest;
```

And yes, the error could be a little more descriptive, but that's the problem here.

Comment: I was trying to do it like java...:(

Comment: C# is not Java. You can't assume everything works the same way.